# Symantec Mail Security MTA Compontents Fail

Tags: symantec

We're using Symantec Mail Security for SMTP. Every so often (perhaps every few weeks) we start getting an email alert like the following:

```
 Symantec Mail Security Alert Notification for xxxx

 ALERT NOTIFICATION

 The following system components are not responding/working:

 Host                     Component                Problem
 Local Host               MTA (Inbound)            Stopped
                          MTA (Outbound)           Stopped
                          MTA (Delivery)           Stopped
```

We continue to get the same alert every hour, on the hour. Mail delivery does not seem to be affected. Restarting the server fixes the issue and messages stop, at least for a few weeks anyways. There has to be a better solution to this than the restart "solution". Better yet, *why* is this happening?

Comment: Are you using Symantec Mail Security for Microsoft Exchange, or Symantec Mail Security for SMTP that you might then have delivering into Exchange?

Comment: Symantec Mail Security for SMTP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the syntax of the error message, it sounds like you're using the Symantec Mail Security for SMTP appliance. We haven't seen these messages before, but it sounds to me like you need to start going through the logs for the appliance.

[image]
<sub>(source: [sysadmin1138.net](http://sysadmin1138.net/images/SMS-SMTP-logs.png))</sub>

Change your type to 'Control Center Logs'. The messages with information that will help diagnose this problem are most likely in the logs with the word "Brightmail" in them. It could be that there is a transient fault that's causing the appliance to restart the MTA queues which is why mail delivery is seemingly unaffected.

I do know that I've had issues similar to this in severity that were resolved in the next code refresh from Symantec, which seems to come out monthly. For instance, a kind of 'filter hub crash' messages was common for a few weeks and went away when we updated the software next.

Comment: Grr... not fair! I waited until he answered re: the question about this being SMSMSE or SMSSMTP before I speculated! >smile<  +1 for this comment, 'cuz it's the right thing to do.